# django admin formfield_for_dbfield raises multiple times

Tags: python, django

I want to change a default widget for `myfield` field in django admin site. I need a `select` widget instead of an `input`. That code works fine:

admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django import forms
from .models import MyModel

CHOICES = (
    ("hello", "hello"),
    ("world", "world")
)

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def formfield_for_dbfield(self, db_field, **kwargs):
        print("Raised: ", db_field, kwargs['request'])
        if db_field.name == 'myfield':
            kwargs['widget'] = forms.Select(choices=CHOICES)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_dbfield(db_field, **kwargs)

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

But there is an issue. `formfield_for_dbfield` function raises multiple times when add/edit page opens. There is a log entry for a single GET request:

```
...
[22/Dec/2015 17:16:34] "GET /static/admin/js/vendor/xregexp/xregexp.min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 62474
[22/Dec/2015 17:16:34] "GET /static/admin/img/tooltag-add.svg HTTP/1.1" 200 331
Raised:  testapp.MyModel.id <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/testapp/mymodel/add/'>
Raised:  testapp.MyModel.myfield <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/testapp/mymodel/add/'>
Raised:  testapp.MyModel.myfield <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/testapp/mymodel/add/'>
Raised:  testapp.MyModel.id <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/testapp/mymodel/add/'>
Raised:  testapp.MyModel.myfield <WSGIRequest: GET '/admin/testapp/mymodel/add/'>
[22/Dec/2015 17:16:39] "GET /admin/testapp/mymodel/add/ HTTP/1.1" 200 5433
[22/Dec/2015 17:16:39] "GET /static/admin/css/forms.css HTTP/1.1" 200 7750
...
```

There is five calls to `formfield_for_db_field`, three of them are related to `myfield`. Why this happens? I have a callable method instead of CHOICES in my project, so I don't want to raise it multiple times in result of each request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found more accurate way to obtain this behavior. The key is to use custom form with overrided `__init__` method, so all the fields may be modified on-the-fly and only once per request. This is an updated version of admin.py:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms import ModelForm, Select
from .models import MyModel


CHOICES = (
    ("hello", "hello"),
    ("world", "world")
)

class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['myfield'].widget = Select(choices=CHOICES)
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('myfield',)

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

The `CHOICES` variable may be replaced by the function, and this function will be called only once.